# Getting string from variable (from imported JS) as key in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, object

How can I make a variable the key to an object?

I am importing constants from definitions.js and these constants I need to use as keys:

```
import * as cons from '../scripts/definitions.js'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cons: cons,
      obj: {
        cons.FILENAMEA: {},
        cons.FILENAMEB: {
          children: [
            cons.CHILDFILENAME1,
            cons.CHILDFILENAME2,
            cons.CHILDFILENAME3
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

With above codes, I am getting error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Because of the dot (.) in `cons.FILENAMEA`. How to do this??
Please note that I need to get these variables/constants from an external file. Not possible to just declare it on the same file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use es6 [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
obj: {
  [cons.FILENAMEA]: {},
  [cons.FILENAMEB]: {
    children: [
      cons.CHILDFILENAME1,
      cons.CHILDFILENAME2,
      cons.CHILDFILENAME3
    ]
  }
}
```

The expression inside the brackets will be evaluated and used as the property name

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Dan's answer is to declare the object before hand and add the key/value pairs to it

```
export default {
  data () {
    const obj = {}
    obj[cons.FILENAMEA] = {}
    obj[cons.FILENAMEB] = {
          children: [
            cons.CHILDFILENAME1,
            cons.CHILDFILENAME2,
            cons.CHILDFILENAME3
          ]
     }
    return {
      cons: cons,
      obj
     }
    }
  }
```